# What is server specification to support 1000 simultaneous users in Liferay Portal?

Tags: liferay

We have installed liferay portal in our server and we want to know if we want to support more than 1,000 simultaneous users what harware is required?
What bandwidth and cpu or ram we need?

Is there any formula or something to get that requirement based on number of users?

Comment: You can visit link http://www.liferay.com/documentation/additional-resources/whitepapers to get help on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pankaj Kathiriya already linked to http://www.liferay.com/documentation/additional-resources/whitepapers in the comment to your question - please look for the "Performance Whitepaper" there. That one highlights 4 different scenarios on a given hardware platform. You'll easily see that the correct answer is "it depends". Now, what does it depend on?

It's the scenario you're implementing: Anonymous access to the site with fully cacheable pages is a different story than highly interactive and permission-controlled access with lots of integration. Also, pure text-based portals will differ in bandwidth requirements from media-rich portlets. And lastly, you can tune Liferay and the related web request to quite some extent, in order to serve static content from other locations etc.

So, read the performance whitepaper, identify the scenario that comes closest to yours and make sure you tune your system if you need more performance.